# setPreference for FirefoxProfile but can not turn off Save dialog

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I use selenium to do automated test with Firefox version 30 for my website (Called it "A").
I 'd like to download a csv file to the defined folder without display Save dialog.
I 've set preferences for FirefoxProfile but it didn't work.

Here is my source code:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
      profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
      profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", screenshotFolderPath); //"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\workspace\\autoTest\\screenshot\\" + screenshotFolderName + "\\" + screenshotFileName + "\\");
      profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
      profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/msword, application/csv, application/ris, text/csv, image/png, application/pdf, text/html, text/plain, application/zip, application/x-zip, application/x-zip-compressed, application/download, application/octet-stream");
      profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
      profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.focusWhenStarting", false);  
      profile.setPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
      profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false);
      profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.alertOnEXEOpen", false);
      profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.closeWhenDone", true);
      profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", false);
      profile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.useWindow", false);
      profile.setPreference("services.sync.prefs.sync.browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false);
      profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile); 
driver.findElement(By.id("btn-download-log")).click();
```

1. Is there something wrong in my source code?
2. I 've tried this source code with another website (Called it "B"). It worked. But in my website ("A"), it didn't. Is there any problem in the source code of my website ("A")?

Sorry for my poor English. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure your site source code is sending back a content header saying the file is `application/csv` to match the preferences you have set.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I 've checked and found that what I downloaded was not a csv file yet. The URL looks like this: "blob:92c881cf-8724-447c-a7b0-d66d34b17b6x". Since then, I changed application/csv to data:application/csv, and it worked.